# Queue all failed transmissions

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsoperationqueue

I'm writting a client/server application that needs to send some XML to a server.

```
NSMutableArray *operations = [NSMutableArray array];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation1 = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest];

[operation1 setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
    float progress = (float)totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead;
    NSLog(@"Progress 1 = %f",progress);
}];
[operations addObject:operation1];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation2 = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest];

[operation2 setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
    float progress = (float)totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead;
    NSLog(@"Progress 2 = %f",progress*100);
}];
[operations addObject:operation2];






NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
// Set the max number of concurrent operations (threads)
[operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:3];
[operationQueue addOperations:@[operation1, operation2] waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

What I want to do now is to handle if the transmission fails and have a queue so it retries to send it.

What's the best way to achieve this with the AFNetworking library ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up it would not be very wise to just retry failed operations again. Depending on what was the source of the error, you risk severe side effects like duplicate submissions.

You're already using AFHTTPRequestOperation, so the easiest solution would be to call 
[setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.1/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperation.html#//api/name/setCompletionBlockWithSuccess%3afailure%3a) and handle errors in the "failure"-block. After all you may also want to use the "success"-block for when the download successfully finished.

One last detail about the code you provided: You're creating the NSArray *operations in line 1 - yet you're not using it for anything since you create a new array of the operations in the last line. So either you left something out or you should simplify that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've changed the code to add the "setCompletionBlockWithSuccess" and handle the failure. I didn't paste the part of the code where I use the array. If not retry the failed operation, what's the best way solution ? I'm actually saving the data not sent to a SQLite database and maybe will do a cron job to send in a background process what have not been sent.

Comment: What to do depends on the error and how you plan to deal with it.
Probably the only reason I can think of for just trying again is when the request failed because the server was done or over capacity. In most other cases you need a more sophisticated problem solution than just trying again.

Comment: The errors are transmission errors, areas where there's no network. That's why I have an SQLite database and I run a scheduled task that retries sending the data not sent.

Comment: Ok, in this case it seems legit to just retry later.
You could check for connectivity using [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) to make sure you can reach your server.